# multi level drop down menu with css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

i want to add multi level dropdown to that w3schools menu.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp
it looks like
[original w3schools menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljeib.jpg)
i tried to make it multi level as you can see.
[multi level drop down photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVawe.jpg)
[multi level drop down photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH6uG.jpg)

My problem is as you can see in the photos; multi level does not close when you are another level. can you fix that ?

```
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
   </div> 
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
 </div>
 
 `/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
 .topnav {
   background-color: #333;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }
 
 /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
 .active {
   background-color: #04AA6D;
   color: white;
 }
 
 /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }
 
 /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
 .dropdown {
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
 .dropdown .dropbtn {
   font-size: 17px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   background-color: inherit;
   font-family: inherit;
   margin: 0;
 }
 
 /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 1;
 }
 
 /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }
 
 /* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
 .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: #555;
   color: white;
 }
 
 /* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
 .dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
 }
 
 /* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
 }
 
 /* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
     display: none;
   }
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }
 
 /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
   .topnav.responsive a.icon {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
   .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
   .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
   .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }
```

i changed it like this;

```
.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
background-color: #04AA6D;
color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 17px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 100%
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
.dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-submenu {
display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
 display: none;
}
.topnav a.icon {
 float: right;
 display: block;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .icon {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}
}
 
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <div class="dropdown-submenu">

   <a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 </div>
</div> 
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to be with the `.dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-submenu  { display: block; }` part, when you're hovering over 'Link 3', you're still hovering over .dropdown-content

Comment: so ? how can i edit the code ?